# How to make a RPN calculator (Java)

Tags: java, calculator, rpn

I have an assignment and I need a bit of help, there seems to be an error when doing more than one calculation using RPN format. I use the example input as given in the link below. On the first input (16 3 7 + *) it gives me the correct answer (160). But, the next two inputs (4 32.125 13 – * 20 +) and (5 –3 * 4 2 / 6 3 1 – / + +) return "error." Thanks for your help in advance, if you need some more information don't be afraid to ask. The assignment details: [Details](http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw6/problems/HPCalculator.htm)

My code so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RPNcalculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String fileName="RPNInput.txt";
    String fileName2="RPNOutput.txt";
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    PrintWriter outputStream = null;

    //read
    try{
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); //try to open the file
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not open the file named "+ fileName); // if it doesn't find it, tell them
        System.exit(0);  // and then exit.
    }

    //write
    try{
        outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName2,true)); //try to create the file
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Could not open the file named "+ fileName2); // if it doesn't find it, tell them
        System.exit(0);  // and then exit.
    }

    while(inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        String equation = inputStream.nextLine();
        if (equation==null)  break;
        Stack<String> tks = new Stack<String>();
        tks.addAll(Arrays.asList(equation.trim().split("[ \t]+"))); //remove spaces and split into list.
          if (tks.peek().equals(""))  continue; //if tks equals nothing
          try  {
            double r = evaluaterpn(tks); //set the variable r to the equation answer.
            if (!tks.empty())  throw new Exception(); //if the list is not empty, print out answer.
            System.out.println(r);
          }
          catch (Exception e)  {System.out.println("error");}
          }
        }


  private static double evaluaterpn(Stack<String> tks) throws Exception  {
        String tk = tks.pop();
        double x,y;
        try  {x = Double.parseDouble(tk);}
        catch (Exception e)  {
          y = evaluaterpn(tks);  x = evaluaterpn(tks);
          if      (tk.equals("+"))  x += y;
          else if (tk.equals("-"))  x -= y;
          else if (tk.equals("*"))  x *= y;
          else if (tk.equals("/"))  x /= y;
          else throw new Exception();
        }
        return x;
      }
}
```

Comment: At a minimum, you want to know what "tk" equals when you throw an "Exception".  Exceptions should generally *tell* you something meaningful about what went wrong.  Yours doesn't :(  IMHO...

Comment: Never throw `Exception`.  Write your own subclass.  Also, do as little as possible in `main`.  Have a `RPNCalculator` object and call instance methods on it.  That way, you can write unit tests.

Comment: Check out my version of the RPN calc https://github.com/stokito/rpn-calc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple :)
you're using the bad "-" sign. When you put a breakpoint at the line "else throw new Exception();", you see that tk is equal to "--" (long "minus" sign). Either copy it into your code instead of normal minus sign or edit your file in a simple text editor.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the problem specifies that you should treat `–` (en dash) as a minus sign.

Comment: Could you specify a bit more? Do i need to just change the "-" to "--" or something further.. thanks for your reply :3

Comment: Well, you can add a condition to this line:

else if (tk.equals("-") || tk.equals("–"))  x -= y;

Comment: hmm.. thank you, it gave me the answer for the second one.. but the third example is still "error".

Comment: Ok, this was a nice one! :)
You can go back to your old code with one condition, but add this line: equation = equation.replaceAll("–", "-"); after this line: Stack<String> tks = new Stack<String>();
The reason for the error is that java can't parse --3 (with long, en dash minus) as a negative three. So, replacing it in the beginning should do the trick!

Comment: @KhalobC Please ask a new question.

Comment: ok, i asked the question here. Thanks again Igor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16470851/rounding-error-gives-me-invalid-answer-java

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Rpncalculator
{

    static final HashMap<String, Integer> prec;

    static
    {
        prec = new HashMap<>();
        prec.put("^", 3);
        prec.put("%", 2);
        prec.put("*", 2);
        prec.put("/", 2);
        prec.put("+", 1);
        prec.put("-", 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Queue<String> infixQueue = new LinkedList<>(); //Standard Queue class provided by Java Framework.
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Double number = 0.0;
        Character c, cNext = ' ';
        String input;
        String multiDigit = "";
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your INFIX expression or 'quit' to exit: ");
            input = sc.nextLine();
            input = input.replaceAll(" ", ""); //ignore spaces in input infix expression
            if (input.equals("quit"))
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
            {
                c = input.charAt(i);
                if (i + 1 < input.length())
                {
                    cNext = input.charAt(i + 1);
                }

                if (c.equals('(') || c.equals(')'))
                {
                    if (c.equals('(') && cNext.equals('-'))
                    {
                        System.out.println("NEGATIVE Numbers not allowed");
                        main(args);
                    } else
                    {
                        infixQueue.add(c.toString());
                    }
                } else if (!Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    if (infixQueue.isEmpty() && c.equals('-'))
                    {
                        System.out.println("NEGATIVE Numbers not allowed");
                        main(args);
                    } else if (cNext.equals('-'))
                    {
                        System.out.println("NEGATIVE Numbers not allowed");
                        main(args);
                    } else
                    {
                        infixQueue.add(c.toString());
                    }
                } else if (Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    if (i + 1 < input.length() && input.charAt(i + 1) == '.') //to handle decimal
                    {
                        int j = i + 1;
                        multiDigit = c.toString() + input.charAt(j); //to handle multidigit
                        while (j + 1 <= input.length() - 1 && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j + 1)))
                        {
                            multiDigit = multiDigit + input.charAt(j + 1);
                            j++;
                        }
                        i = j;
                        infixQueue.add(multiDigit);
                        multiDigit = "";
                    } else if (i + 1 <= input.length() - 1 && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i + 1)))
                    {
                        int j = i;
                        //multiDigit=c.toString()+input.charAt(i);
                        while (j <= input.length() - 1 && Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j)))
                        {
                            multiDigit = multiDigit + input.charAt(j);
                            j++;
                        }
                        i = j - 1;
                        infixQueue.add(multiDigit);
                        multiDigit = "";
                    } else
                    {
                        infixQueue.add(c.toString());
                    }

                }
            }

            infixToPostfix(infixQueue);
        } while (!input.equals("quit"));
    }

    //method to convert from infix to postfix
    public static void infixToPostfix(Queue<String> infixQueue)
    {
        Stack operatorStack = new Stack();
        Queue<String> postQueue = new LinkedList<>();
        String t;
        while (!infixQueue.isEmpty())
        {
            t = infixQueue.poll();
            try
            {
                double num = Double.parseDouble(t);
                postQueue.add(t);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                if (operatorStack.isEmpty())
                {
                    operatorStack.add(t);
                } else if (t.equals("("))
                {
                    operatorStack.add(t);
                } else if (t.equals(")"))
                {
                    while (!operatorStack.peek().toString().equals("("))
                    {
                        postQueue.add(operatorStack.peek().toString());
                        operatorStack.pop();
                    }
                    operatorStack.pop();
                } else
                {
                    while (!operatorStack.empty() && !operatorStack.peek().toString().equals("(") && prec.get(t) <= prec.get(operatorStack.peek().toString()))
                    {
                        postQueue.add(operatorStack.peek().toString());
                        operatorStack.pop();
                    }
                    operatorStack.push(t);
                }
            }
        }
        while (!operatorStack.empty())
        {
            postQueue.add(operatorStack.peek().toString());
            operatorStack.pop();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your POSTFIX expression is: ");
        //numbers and operators all seperated by 1 space.
        for (String val : postQueue)
        {
            System.out.print(val + " ");
        }
        postfixEvaluation(postQueue);
    }

    //method to calculate the reuslt of postfix expression.
    public static void postfixEvaluation(Queue<String> postQueue)
    {
        Stack<String> eval = new Stack<>(); //Standard Stack class provided by Java Framework.
        String t;
        Double headNumber, nextNumber, result = 0.0;
        while (!postQueue.isEmpty())
        {
            t = postQueue.poll();
            try
            {
                double num = Double.parseDouble(t);
                eval.add(t);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
            {
                headNumber = Double.parseDouble(eval.peek());
                eval.pop();
                nextNumber = Double.parseDouble(eval.peek());
                eval.pop();

                switch (t)
                {
                    case "+":
                        result = nextNumber + headNumber;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        result = nextNumber - headNumber;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        result = nextNumber * headNumber;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        //in java, there is no exception generated when divided by zero and thus checking
                        //for 
                        if (headNumber == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("\nERROR: Cannot Divide by zero!\n");
                            return;
                        } else
                        {
                            result = nextNumber / headNumber;
                            break;
                        }
                    case "%":
                        result = nextNumber % headNumber;
                        break;
                    case "^":
                        result = Math.pow(nextNumber, headNumber);
                        break;

                }

                eval.push(result.toString());

            }

        }
        //Outputing the result in this function to verify that the o/p is a result of postfix expression.
        //Outputing the result to 3 decimal places
        System.out.println("\nRESULT is: ");
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
        for (String val : eval)
        {
            System.out.println(df.format(Double.parseDouble(val)) + "\n");
        }
    }

}
```