# how to write a postfix calculator in java to calculate multiple-expression evaluation?

Tags: java, calculator, rpn

I want to write a java program that it is capable of evaluating expressions which contain more than two operands and one operator. Such expressions should be evaluated left to right, with the result of the previous operation becoming the first operand into the next operation. For example: 20  5  -  3  +

P.S It is not a homework. Just for practice. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Any help would be appreciated.` - start coding and ask a specific question when you have a problem. `Just for practice` - trying is how you learn. You might not get it right the first time but you learn something new every time you try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469245/how-to-make-a-rpn-calculator-java?rq=1 no?

Comment: Most of the codes i have come across used stack. Since i am a beginner, i am having a hard time understanding stack. Any method without stack might be easier.